# Detect when app is opened with a service

Tags: android

I want to be able to detect when an application is opened and notify the user of something at the moment related to that same application but I don't know how to do this.

1. The user opens my app
2. I intent the service (background / foreground) and it successfully starts
3. Whenever the user opens another application I want to "catch it" and present a notification to the user

How can this be made? Are there any event listeners i need to use? Thank you very much.

Comment: You are welcome,study this http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html

Comment: There are no "event listeners" for this, as there are no events for this (e.g., broadcasts).

Comment: The question as stated can't be done. To write an application that knows about each app the user runs, the straightforward thing to do is to write an app launcher. There are many apps like this available for android, and it is possible to write your own.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to catch "open app" intents in general, then it depends on how the app defined the intent. If it specified a class (explicit intent) then it will generally not be visible to your app unless the device is rooted, for example.

Implicit intents are broadcast and you simply need to define an intent filter in order to receive them. These are intents that allow Android and/or the user to select the appropriate app target based on data sent with the intent.

There are both useful and malicious motivations to do the kind of thing you are asking about. Read this:

[Android Intent Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888240/android-intent-security)

And also the posted comment on learning about intents overall.

Answer (score -1):

This is really simple. Here I am trying to figure out the solution. When your app goes on `onPause()` state then broadcast a message using `BroadcastReceiver`. On the other hand in another app just register for that broadcast.

Comment: so, the service is not needed?